# How can I get all possible addresses with lat and long by city or district prefix?

Tags: python, api, geolocation, openstreetmap

I want to implement code like below:

When I send request to endpoint with  name of "**Sig**" (just an example),I need it to give me

```
[

 {
  "name ":"Sighisoara",
  "lat":"smth",
  "Long":"smth"

 },

 {
  "name ":"Sigulda",
  "lat":"smth",
  "Long":"smth"
 }
]
```

Currently, I use **OpenStreetMap**, It has no such functionality. To get a address, you should write exactly how the address is spelled. For example, to get **Sighisoara**, you need to write **Sighisoara**
Any idea to do that or   free **api** which provides such functionality.

**PS, I am using Python.**

Comment: If API you're using does not support such wildcards you probably cannot work this around. If possible you could fetch all addresses (preferably in chunks) and filter them on your side.

Comment: I mean maybe is there an api with that functionality. I can freely switch to it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the point is for you to understand the structure of this dictionary that contains all the city names，and you can try to split the structures.
For example, I got a dictionary of weather from an API here, and I want to print out the current temperature.

weather ={'coord': {'lon': 113.25, 'lat': 23.1167}, 'weather': [{'id': 803, 'main': 'Clouds', 'description': 'broken clouds', 'icon': '04d'}], 'base': 'stations', 'main': {'temp': 298.18, 'feels_like': 298.31, 'temp_min': 295.37, 'temp_max': 299.82, 'pressure': 1018, 'humidity': 53}, 'visibility': 6000, 'wind': {'speed': 2, 'deg': 160}, 'clouds': {'all': 75}, 'dt': 1615355271, 'sys': {'type': 1, 'id': 9620, 'country': 'CN', 'sunrise': 1615329655, 'sunset': 1615372438}, 'timezone': 28800, 'id': 1809858, 'name': 'Guangzhou', 'cod': 200}
This is the code I will use:
current_temp = (weather['main']['temp'])
The name of this dictionary is weather, inside of it , there are several lists of 'main', which contained the 'temp' I want. So you can make sure if your code is correctly catch the structure.

Comment: Could someone please give me a upvote as encouragement to continue answering more questions. Thank you very much!